# Log4j to create dynamic files

Tags: java, log4j

I have a file processing JAVA Code, While processing files, I want to log all the file processing details like file has this no of lines and it has some "Hello" Strings in a Seperate Log file for Each file am processing.

The code I tried here works fine, but if I have 2 file like file1.txt and file2.txt.The logger logs file1.txt details in log_file1.log then while log the file2.txt in log_file2.log it retains the log_file1.log contents also in log_file2.log .

**File1.txt**

```
Hello How are you
Hello How are you
```

**log_file1.log**

```
it has 2 lines and 2 Hello Strings
```

**File2.txt**

```
Hello How are you
Hello How are you
Hello How are you
```

**log_file2.log**

```
it has 2 lines and 2 Hello Strings
it has 3 lines and 3 Hello Strings
```

**Code I tried :**

```
public class DummyLog
{
    private static PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout("%d{ISO8601}\t%p\t%c\t%m%n");

    public static Logger getLogger(String fileName, Class clazz) throws Exception
        {
            fileName = "D:/New folder/log-properties/" + fileName + ".log";
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
            FileAppender appender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(patternLayout,
                            fileName, "'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
            logger.addAppender(appender);
            logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
            return logger;
        }
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
public class TestDummyLog
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        for(int i = 2;i > 0;i--)
        {           
                 String loggerName = "Log1_"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMHHmmssSSS").format(new Date());
                 Logger logger = DummyLog.getLogger(loggerName, TestDummyLog.class);
                 logger.info("Joseph Micheal TestLogger:" +new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMHHmmssSSS").format(new Date()));
                 new TestLoggerChild().getChileStuff(loggerName);
                 Thread.sleep(6000);
        }

    }
}
```

**Child Class :**

```
public class TestLoggerChild
{
public static Logger logger = null;
public void getChileStuff(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    logger = DummyLog.getLogger(fileName,TestLoggerChild.class);
    logger.info("Child Sample info message"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMHHmmssSSS").format(new Date()));
    logger.info("Class :::::: TestLoggerChild.class");
    logger.debug("fileName @@@@@@@@@@@@@:" + fileName);
    logger.info("Sample info message");
    logger.warn("Sample warn message");
    logger.error("Sample error message");
    logger.info("Sample info message ");
    logger.info("Class :::::: TestLoggerChild.class");
}
}
```

Comment: sorry can you rephrase you description of the problem? I did not get it :-( Do you have a problem with rolling log files?

Comment: Thanks for reply please check the updated Description.

Comment: try logger.setAdditivity(false)

Comment: I tried this is not working !

Comment: Is it neccessary to have same category (TestLoggerChild.class)? If you pass your custom parameterized string instead, it must work. DummyLog.getLogger(fileName,"Category" + i); - i is passed from TestDummyLog

Comment: please make it as answer Thank you it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it neccessary to use the same category (TestLoggerChild.class)? If you pass your custom parameterized string instead, it must work: DummyLog.getLogger(fileName,"Category" + i);